# I can't size div at 100% of length

Tags: html, css

http://hyp.altervista.org/index.html

I have a problem with css.

```
    .sfondobianco{
        background-color:#ffffff;
        z-index: 4;
        position:absolute;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;

        }

    .menusinistra{

        background-color:#f6f7f8;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        width:25%;
        border:0px;
        left:0px;
        font-family:fantasy;  

        float: left;
        border-right:2px solid #757575;
        }

    .contenitoredestra{

        float: left;

        width: 75%;    
        background-color: bisque;
        }

    .contenitore{
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;   
        }
```

I want that `contenitoredestra` and `menusinistra` cover the 100% of the page length. I can't do it and I don't know why. Maybe for problem with the upper div.

In addition I want `menusinistra` height depending of `contenitoredestra` length without table and table cell. Can you help me?

HTML part:

```
    <div class="sfondobianco">
        <div class="menusinistra">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Big-GYM/1567454133517054"
                data-width="500px" height="600px" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true">
                <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Big-GYM/1567454133517054"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Big-GYM/1567454133517054">Big GYM</a></blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenitoredestra">

        <div class="banner"> <img src="images/save.png" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"> </div>

        <div class="container marketing contenitore">
            ooooooooooooooooooo
        </div>
        <!-- /.container --> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: i add the link of the page... it's too long

Comment: I said *relevant* HTML, not all of it. Remove everything that isn't important to the question. External links just aren't good enough I'm afraid.

Comment: i forgot the part    width: 100% in sfondobianco. I need help for the height of div menusinistra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly just add `display: flex;` to `.sfondobianco`. Ie:

```
.sfondobianco{
   background-color:#ffffff;
   z-index: 4;
   position:absolute;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Becomes:

```
.sfondobianco{
   background-color:#ffffff;
   z-index: 4;
   position:absolute;

   display:flex;
}
```

Also removed the padding because it's redundant.